# pecl install pecl_http not working.

Tags: php, apache, http, pecl

I have installed the http extension for php by using the following command,

```
**pecl install pecl_http**
```

Its successfull, But I cannot find the http.so extension in my 
**/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs** folder. 
Is there anything I have to do?

Comment: Are there any other directories (with another date) in  /usr/lib/php5/?

Comment: No, there are no directories in /usr/lib/ph5. 
    20121212+lfs,json,build are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve acheived http posting using the following function. 
I just found it in internet.

function http_post_lite($url, $data, $headers=null) {

```
$data = http_build_query($data);    
$opts = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => $data,'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"));


if($headers) {
    $opts['http']['header'] = $headers;
}
$st = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $st);

if(!$fp) {
    return false;
}
return stream_get_contents($fp);
}
```